# Allow access to Apache server from .local name in URL

Tags: apache-http-server, access-control

I am running an Apache server on one of my macs in my local network.

At the same time in my `httpd.conf` file I allow all the computers in the local network to access it using

```
allow from 192.168.1.
```

This allows access in the form `http://192.168.1.x` but NOT in the form `http://server.local`.

What other IPs do I have to allow for the DNS name to be resolved?

(when I `allow all` it works by the way). Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to allow any IP addresses access, you need to set up DNS or add the name to the `hosts` file on all other devices.

Answer (score 0):

The "name.local" form is as far as i know a part of [Apple Bonjour network zero-configuration protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Bonjour).

The easiest way to resolve name.local on other computers is to add a line in the hosts files of said computers.

The [Bonjour Browser for Windows](http://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourBrowser) may help you to find your server from Windows Computers.

As far as i known, GNU/Linux OS have a Bonjour like (zero-configuration) protocol support in the form of [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29). There is some compatiblity library available (on Ubuntu Saucy Salamander, in the package libavahi-compat-libdnssd1)

As for the Apache 2 configuration, you need a ServerName line, and may be a better written allow from:

```
ServerName name.local
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

For localhost access, you may need to add:

```
ServerAlias localhost
```

Comment: Thank you. ServerName name.local worked!! BTW, before it worked on Firefox and NOT on Safari, but now it works on both. You do not happen to know why?

Comment: Firefox may have a better support of available local web services :D. URL resolution is quite specifics to the browsers.

Comment: Another weird observation. Safari (v 6.1.1) on the "server" still will not resolve it but Safari (v 7.0.1) on "client" works after the ServerName change. Weird!

Comment: edited with a possible answer.